# Retry strategy/framework for doing retry on result for failed insertions

Tags: java, retry-logic

I'm making a service call with some input objects to a database. Few of the objects succeed and rest of them fail with a reason. I want to have an exponential retry strategy to trigger the same call with the failed objects.

Is there any framework i can use with a defined retry strategy in java

Example call

```
Output output = mDbService.persist(List<Objects> objects)
```

The output of the service call looks like

```
class Output {
    int successCount;
    List<FailedObject> failedObject;
}

// Each failedObject has a structure

class FailedObject {
   Object object;
   int errorCode; // Some are retryable and other are not.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know, a framework seems overkill, but maybe I’m misunderstanding your question.

Would something like this do what you want?

```
Output output = mDbService.persist(objects);
while(output.failedObject.size() > 0){
    List<Object> retryList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(FailedObject failed:output.failedObject){
        if(shouldRetry(failed.errorCode)){
            retryList.add(failed.object);
        }
    }
    output = mDbService.persist(retryList);
}
```

You will naturally also have to provide an implementation that checks the error code and performs the logic to determine if the associated object should be retried or not.

```
private boolean shouldRetry(int errorCode){
    // your logic here
}
```

Comment: Of course this is the traditional way. But, i want to do an exponential retry strategy with a wait time before retrying the failed DSNs. can any framework like FailSafe as such help here?